# Bootstrap carousel on select radio button not working on next slide as its working fine on first slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bootstrap carousel and added condition on next prev slide with jQuery, its working fine on first slide but on next slide its not working, below is my HTML of carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-personal-loan" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row per-loan-gender">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title">My gender</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <label>
                                <img src="1.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
                                <span>Male</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <label>
                                <img src="2.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                                <span>Female</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row per-loan-city">
          <div class="quote-title">Where do you live currently?</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="3.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hyderabad" value="hyderabad">
                        <span>Hyderabad</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="4.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="chennai" value="chennai">
                        <span>Chennai</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="5.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="bangalore" value="bangalore">
                        <span>Bangalore</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="6.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hosur" value="hosur">
                        <span>Hosur</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="7.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="other_city" value="other city">
                        <span>Other City</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="item">
          <div class="row per-loan-sources">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row sal_or_self">
                        <div class="quote-title">Are You</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="8.png" />
                                <span>Salaried</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="9.png" />
                                <span>Self-employed</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
<div class="row per-loan-sources">
    <div class="quote-title" msg="Required Loan amount">Required Loan amount(Sal)<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" name="loanAmount" id="loanAmount"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
         <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-slide">Previous</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row per-loan-sources">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title">Ever Defaulted on any Loan Or Credit card?</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="10.png" />
                                <span>Yes</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="11.png" />
                                <span>No</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Below is my jQuery code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel({
    interval:false,
    wrap:false
});

jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    if (jQuery("input[name='gender']:checked").length<=0) {
            alert('Please select your gender');
            jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');
            return false;
        }
    else if (jQuery("input[name='gender']:checked").length>0){
        jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('cycle');
        return true;
    }
    else if (jQuery("input[name='livecity']:checked").length<=0) {
        alert('Please select your city');
        jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('cycle');
        return true;
    }
});
```

});

As you can check on Quote Loan(Testing) on http://dev.makemyloans.com/ here condition on male and female working fine but when its go to next slide on city its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its working fine on first slide but on next slide its not working

This happens because you are looking for checked radio buttons inside the whole carousel instead of the current active carousel item.
Change this line:

```
jQuery("input[name='gender']:checked")
```

with:

```
jQuery(this).find(".active :checked")
```

Moreover, with bootstrap you can use a modal instead of the javascript alert. And you can set an attribute to each carousel title like:

```
<div class="quote-title" msg="Please select your gender">My gender</div>
```

in order to have a message text there instead to compute it dynamically.

Of course there are many possibilities to achieve this, but I would suggest this to simplify your code:

```
$('#carousel-personal-loan').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
 if (jQuery(this).find(".active :checked").length<=0) {
     $('#msgModal').find('.modal-body p').text(jQuery(this).find(".active .quote-title").attr('msg'));
     $('#msgModal').modal('show');
     $('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');
     return false;
 }
 $('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('cycle');
});
```

Remember to add the modal div fragment (see the end of snippet).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel({
        interval:false,
        wrap:false
    });

    jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        if (jQuery(this).find(".active :checked").length<=0) {
            $('#msgModal').find('.modal-body p').text(jQuery(this).find(".active .quote-title").attr('msg'));
            $('#msgModal').modal('show');
            jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');
            return false;
        }
        jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('cycle');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carousel-personal-loan" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row per-loan-gender">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title" msg="Please select your gender">My gender</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <label>
                                <img src="1.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
                                <span>Male</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <label>
                                <img src="2.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                                <span>Female</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row per-loan-city">
                <div class="quote-title" msg="Please select the place where you live.">Where do you live currently?</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="3.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hyderabad" value="hyderabad">
                        <span>Hyderabad</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="4.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="chennai" value="chennai">
                        <span>Chennai</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="5.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="bangalore" value="bangalore">
                        <span>Bangalore</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="6.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hosur" value="hosur">
                        <span>Hosur</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="7.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="other_city" value="other city">
                        <span>Other City</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row per-loan-sources">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row sal_or_self">
                        <div class="quote-title" msg="Please select: Are you....">Are You</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="8.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="areyou" value="...">
                                <span>Salaried</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="9.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="areyou" value="...">
                                <span>Self-employed</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row per-loan-sources">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title"  msg="Please select default on loan...">Ever Defaulted on any Loan Or Credit card?</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="10.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="defonloan" value="...">
                                <span>Yes</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="11.png" />
                                <input type="radio" name="defonloan" value="...">
                                <span>No</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<!--  MODAL ADDED  -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="msgModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- MODAL END -->
```

Comment: Great! your answer is perfectly fine and I am able to work on next step now, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have added text type field now in this slider but it is also validating as like radio button and not allow me to go back or next?

Comment: @Barjinder I tested the snippet adding new input type text and I get no error. All works fine.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find where you have added text field? As I'm checking on my site to add as text field its also behaving like radio button validation and not allow me to go to next slide.

Comment: As you can see I have added new text field in my question HTML code "Required Loan amount(Sal)" and its not working on my site and not allow me to go to next slide.